# How do I updating only certain columns, with an Android Room entity?

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

Unfortunately, the @Update annotation only has limited functionality in the form of conflict resolution. My entities contain data that is remote, immutable, or local. So, when an entity is updated from a remote source, I need to retain, or ignore, updates to certain columns.

I want to build an update that takes an object from a remote source, and only updates certain columns.

**My entity looks like this:**

```
@Entity
public class MyExample {
    @PrimaryKey
    public String remoteId;
    private String first;
    private String second;
    // This property is local only, don't want it reset.
    private String third;
    // constructor, getter and setter
}
```

**This is what I am doing now:**

```
@Query("UPDATE my_example SET first = :first, second = :second, WHERE remoteId = :remoteId")
protected abstract int updateRemote(String remoteId, String first, String second);
```

*Note that "third" is not updated.*

However, that is very tedious and time consuming to write from scratch every time I want to add a new entity.

**What I want to be able to do:**

```
@Query("UPDATE my_example SET first = :entity.first, second = :entity.second, WHERE remoteId = :entity.remoteId")
protected abstract int updateRemote(MyExample entity);
```

*OR*

@Query("UPDATE my_example SET first, second VALUES(entity) WHERE remoteId = :entity.remoteId")
    protected abstract int updateRemote(MyExample entity);

*OR*

```
@Query("UPDATE my_example SET first = :entity.first, second = :entity.second, WHERE remoteId = :entity.remoteId")
protected abstract int updateRemote(MyExample entity);
```

*OR*

```
@Update(columns={"first", "second"})
protected abstract int updateRemote(MyExample entity);
```

Any of those would mean I don't have the name each param in the method, I could just pass the entity as I would for a normal @Update.

To make this even better, would be able to annotate columns that were only set during @Insert, or @Update.

Does anyone know of a way to do this, without having the specify each inout parameter?